# Dynamically changing UL style

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I'm having an unordered list with a few "li" elements. The idea is to highlight the current "li" which is currently in focus(onhover).

Using some code like this

```
li[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
    this.style.borderLeft='5px solid red';
    this.style.listStyle = 'square';
};
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNqaV/1/)

I want a left border to appear on hovered element, which is happening in the fiddle. But that seems to shift the text towards the right. How do I get rid of that jumping text behavior?

My next question is can we create our own symbols for ul. Currently I am toggling between a square and disc. Is it possible to have fancy icons on each "li"?

Comment: because of you adding a `5px border` in `li` check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/XNqaV/3/).

The HTML:

```
<h1>Introduction to the DOM</h1>
<p class="test">There are a number of reasons why the
DOM is awesome, here are some:</p>
<ul>
<li id="everywhere">It can be found everywhere.</li>
<li class="test">It's easy to use.</li>
<li class="test">It can help you to find what you want, really quickly.</li>
</ul>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for ( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ) {
    li[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
        this.style.borderLeft='5px solid red';
        this.style.listStyle = 'square';
    };
    li[i].onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        this.style.borderLeft='';
        this.style.listStyle = 'disc';
    };
}
```

The CSS:

```
ul li {line-height:30px; padding-left: 10px; border-left:5px solid transparent;}
#element {
    background: linear-gradient(top, black 0%, white 100%);
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Any thoughts about my second question?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, kindly accept by a green tick and upvote. Thank you. - @Uzair

Comment: Yes you can put symbols. Refer this link for more details. http://www.artishock.net/coding/css-list-styling-using-ascii-special-characters/ - @Uzair

Answer (score 1):

Add a transparent border of the same width when you are not hovering, also, instead of changing styles dynamically, please just change the className and keep the styles where they belong.

Even better if you can use the pseudo-element :hover (unless you really need to support IE.. argh..)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can do it by a css trick
add this to your css

```
ul li {line-height:30px; padding-left: 15px; border-left:5px solid white}
```

it works fine here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/XNqaV/2/

Comment: and the trick is adding a white border initially with 5px width. :)

Comment: also you can use `transparent border` however you want

Comment: This is a valid as long as my background color is white(or whatever which doesn't change). But what if I told you the background color of the page is an image with color variations thoughout?

Comment: i think it'll fill all conditions

Comment: what is your exact condition let me know i'll find the solution for that particular condition

Comment: I suggest to make the background to transparent from white. This will work in all conditions. - @TheMechanic.

Comment: I have put the solution for your purpose. You can compare it with your fiddle and check it. - @Uzair

Comment: @NathanLee also i have declare in my answer use however you want transparent or white or whatever this will work in all condition